# In your experience what NetLogo models are best suited for teaching about population growth and natural selection?

Tags: netlogo

I want to teach a first year biology class about population dynamics and natural selection and thought a NetLogo model would be a neat way to do so. I'd love to hear your recommendations for models that you've used for teaching.

I appreciate my question is a little off topic but this is the hub of NetLogo activity on the internet.

Comment: Are you able to code in NetLogo yourself, or are you looking for recommendations for models from the library and publicly accessible sources? I'd be starting with the altruism and related models from the library.

Comment: I can code, but for the class it would be more illustrative, so focusing on the interface of the models.

Comment: Wolf sheep predation is simple and easy to understand for a predator/prey population dynamics example, and maybe one of the versions of Bug Hunt for selection? I like the camoflage option. They're both pretty simplistic (not in a bad way) so how much time you want to spend may determine if they are substantial enough for what you need

Comment: this question is likely to be closed as being off-topic for Stack Overflow, which is for coding questions specifically. try https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/netlogo-users